# Why object's attributes are not there when the class is instantiated?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why instantiating a class does not instantiate all its attributes ? I think a very simple example could explain my problem better:

```
class Example:
    def example(self):
        self.var=10

if __name__=='__main__':
    E=Example()
    # In this case, the attribute  var is not instantiated
    try:
        attr=getattr(E,"var")
        print(attr) # <-- it does not exist even if E instantiated Example class
    except AttributeError:
        print("Object not having this attribute") # <-- This is the output
```

Why the object *E* does not have all its attributes instantiated (namely the attribute *var*) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your class if you need to initialize var you need to call it `explicitly` by calling the `example method` in the `example class`

but if if you write `__init__` method it it automatically initialize the variable at the time of object creation

> *The **init** method (init for initialise) is called when the object is instantiated. Instantiation is done by (effectively) calling the
>   class.Here a new instance is created. Then its **init** method is called .it call the example method to initialize  `var` in the exapme*

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var=0 # or you can directly give self.var=10
        self.example()
    def example(self):
        self.var=10

if __name__=='__main__':
    E=Example()
    # In this case, the attribute  var is not instantiated
    try:
        attr=getattr(E,"var")
        print(attr) # <-- it does not exist even if E instantiated Example class
    except AttributeError:
        print("Object not having this attribute")
```

other way of doing is

when you intalized class object call the method in it

```
E=Example()
E.example()#explicitly call example method in the class
```

Comment: Ok, that is a full explanation. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Java, in Python, the initiator function is called `__init__`; naming the method like the name of the class does not create a constructor.

So, when you instantiate an object of class `Example`, the method `example` is not called and your attribute doesn't exist. You'll have to call it explicitly, like this:

```
>>> e = Example()
>>> e.example()
>>> e.var
10
```

To have the attribute available to all objects at instantiation, modify your class and create a `__init__` method, like this:

```
class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 10
```

Now, it will work as you expect:

```
>>> e = Example()
>>> e.var
10
```

Answer (score 1):

You not called `example` method which sets `var` to `self`.

try

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    E=Example()
    E.example()
    # In this case, the attribute  var is not instantiated
    try:
        attr=getattr(E,"var")
        print(attr)
    except AttributeError:
        print("Object not having this attribute")
```